# How to initialize and compare dates (such as production/ expiration date of a product) in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to create two variables as the production date and expiration date for my agent "Product" in AnyLogic and then compare the expiration date to the current date of the model to find out if it's expired.
I modeled the variables as Date:

```
Date productionRDate;
Date expirationRDate = addToDate(productionRDate, DAY, 30);
```

and compare expirationRDate to the current date like this:

```
differenceInCalendarUnits(DAY, agent.expirationRDate, date()) > 0
```

and initialized productionRDate as in the image below. But it has an error that says:
[initialization and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTuAK.png)

Any suggestion on what should I do?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Share a screenshot, code looks OK

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize productionDate as well, it is currently empty, so you cannot add to it.

Do something like

Date productionDate =date();

It needs to have a value

Comment: Great. Please upvote answers that were helpful, future users with similar problems will find the answer faster, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote